# HTML The Border not showing up in my form

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and i asked my teacher but he just told me to google so...

[I want to create a border like this, the ones surrounding, size,crust etc but it doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbCHR.png)

[Mine looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLBpW.png)

[My code looks smth like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKjHm.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to do so?? I thought it was a problem with the CSS or something but then my teacher said it wasnt using css to make that border afterwards so Im just confused now.

My code is like this:

```css
form {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 10px solid olive;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h1>Pizza Order Form</h1>
    <label>Pizza Type:</label>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option>Aloha Chicken</option>
        <option>Beef Pepperoni</option>
        <option>Chicken Delight</option>
        <option>Deluxe Cheese</option>
    </select>

    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="4" value="1" /> <br /><br />

    <div>
        <label>Size:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="small" />
        <label for="small">Small</label>
        <input type="radio" id="medium" />
        <label for="medium">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" id="large" />
        <label for="large">Large</label>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
        <label>Crust:</label>
        <input type="radio" id="thin" />
        <label for="thin">Thin</label>
        <input type="radio" id="thick" />
        <label for="thick">Thick</label>
        <input type="radio" id="deep dish" />
        <label for="deep dish">Deep Dish</label>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div>
        <label>Toppings:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Mushroom" />
        <label for="Mushroom">Mushroom</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Sausage" />
        <label for="Sausage">Sausage</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Olives" />
        <label for="Olives">Olives</label>
    </div>

    <br />
    <label>Addons:</label>
    <select>
        <option>Please select addons if required</option>
        <option>Side of Buffalo Wings</option>
        <option>Garlic Bread</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Go check out the [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) element (and its companion, `legend`) - that has the purpose of grouping form fields, and it renders the borders you want by default.

Answer (score -1):

I updated here please check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vqr9xu?file=index.html) use `fieldset`

Answer (score -1):

checkout [this](https://codepen.io/jigsmo/pen/LYjyEyN) codepen. this might help you :)

For HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    form details
  </div>
</div>
```

For CSS:

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 4px;

}
.container .content {
  border: 10px solid olive; 
  height: 100%;
}
```